# CakePHP 3 case count query returning true and not integer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I using the CakePHP 3 query builder to count records. One of the results of the count returns `true` instead of the actual integer of 2. If I was to run the outputed MySQL in PHPAdmin then I see all integers. Seems very strange.

The table field of `invitation_sent` is a boolean

```
$query = $this->Guests->find('all', $options);

$inviteNotSent = $query->newExpr()
    ->addCase(
        $query->newExpr()->add(['invitation_sent' => 0]),
        1,
        'integer'
    );
$inviteSent = $query->newExpr()
    ->addCase(
        $query->newExpr()->add(['invitation_sent' => 1]),
        1,
        'integer'
    );

$query->select([
    'invitation_not_sent' => $query->func()->count($inviteNotSent),
    'invitation_sent' => $query->func()->count($inviteSent)
]);

$query->hydrate(false);
$result = $query->toList();
```

The MySQL generate is

```
SELECT 
  (
    COUNT(
      (
        CASE WHEN invitation_sent = 0 THEN 1 END
      )
    )
  ) AS `invitation_not_sent`, 
  (
    COUNT(
      (
        CASE WHEN invitation_sent = 1 THEN 1 END
      )
    )
  ) AS `invitation_sent`
FROM 
  guests Guests
```

CakePHP returned result is

```
result (array)
     0 (array)
         invitation_not_sent 0
         invitation_sent (true)
```

Expected result

```
result (array)
     0 (array)
         invitation_not_sent 0
         invitation_sent 2
```

Comment: Am I right to assume that the existing `invitation_sent` column is of type `TINYINT(1)`?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `invitation_sent` column is of a boolean type, hence you'll end up with `true` instead of the numeric value, that's the expected result. Neither will disabling hydration prevent this, as hydration (converting data sets into entities) is separate from casting, nor does defining `integer` in the `addCase()` method affect this, as that type is only used for input casting.

I'd suggest to generally avoid using existing column names when computing columns, unless there's an actual need to do so. Simple fix, just use different names, plurals for example would make sense from a linguistical point of view too (eg `invitations_*`).

By default columns that do not exist in the table schema would be returned as strings, if you wanted them to be casted to integers, you could modify the select type map accordingly.

```
$query->select([
    'invitations_not_sent' => $query->func()->count($inviteNotSent),
    'invitations_sent' => $query->func()->count($inviteSent)
]);

$query->selectTypeMap()->addDefaults([
    'invitations_not_sent' => 'integer',
    'invitations_sent' => 'integer'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation